# Moderator tool: add links to the "already has an answer here:" header

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, duplicate-questions, moderator-tools

With the old closed-as-duplicate system we could add links to the "**Possible Duplicate:**" header.
As a moderator this was helpful for directing people to a group of very similar questions.

- With the new "**This question already has an answer here:**" header we cannot edit that area.
- Please add a moderator ability to include additional post links to that field.

As it is I can only suggest that regular users vote to close as duplicate of certain posts, wait, and then cast a super-vote (selecting a different post).  This seems inefficient compared the the previous system.