# Duplicate question close reason says "already has an answer," which is often false

Tags: bug, closed-questions, duplicate-questions, wording

I [asked a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179350/adzerk-vote-icons-appearing-on-so-with-no-adverts-present) here on MSO today, but it was found to have been asked [around a month ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175301/invisible-advert-not-quite-invisible).

I'm not concerned by this (better to be found by more than one user) but, I noticed that the wording in the closure statement is factually incorrect:

[image]

No it doesn't have an answer - Not even a ***sniff*** of one!

This statement, logically, ***should*** be factually accurate and reflect the existence of answers and include singular/plural references to them - or at a minimum use language that covers both scenarios.

**Edit:** As a result of my question, [an answer has been given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175301/invisible-advert-not-quite-invisible/179360#179360) and the bug in question has been remedied, but this question still remains valid.

Comment: Other examples include a question closed as a duplicate of a closure, such as not constructive / not a real question.

Comment: @JasonSturges Yes, I've just looked at those. Generalised statements are fine. But its important to get them right.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Thanks for the link, but this doesn't change the fact that it's still just inaccurate.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this is implemented, but updating the close reason when the number of answers on the original change is probably not feasible. It'd require extra checks and queries for very little actual benefit. So long as the wording covers *most* of the cases - and I believe it does now that we require all common dupe closures to list an answered question as the original - I'd say it's good enough.

Comment: @AnnaLear Understood, but the number of answers are already recorded at the top of any post - see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179326/can-we-be-more-specific-as-to-why-a-question-is-narq) for an example (_24 answers_). So, potentially no extra queries.

Comment: @nickhar The number of answers would have to come from the original(s), not the question that's closed. I'm not sure what info we have readily available about those questions when we display the closed one.

Comment: @AnnaLear It does; he's talking about the box at the top of the post. "This question already has an answer here: [Help us make “Not Constructive” and “Not a Real Question” closures more effective](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv) *24 answers*". The "24 answers" is talking about the linked post, not the current one

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Oh, *that* thing. Yeah, good point. I forgot about that.

Comment: @Anna worth to mention that the top banner in the post **is** dynamic and show different text. For example [this closed question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172311/152859) shows "This question is an exact duplicate of" as the dupe has no answers. So implementing same logic in the "marked as duplicate" banner shouldn't be complicated or expansive, it's all in there already.

Comment: This bug also affects the vote to close dialog - many people may not be aware that you *can* vote to close as a duplicate of a closed question with zero answers.

Comment: @AdamLear can you please at least post what you said in the first comment (request not feasible) as answer on the root request, so that people won't hold their breath waiting?