# Make the closed-as-duplicate indicator grammatically correct

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, close-reasons

I just noticed this:

> ### marked as duplicate by Bob, John, Joe, Jill, Jane 8 millennia ago

I'm interested in the *marked as duplicate* part.

I believe that before the big close reason change it said 'marked as *a* duplicate'.

Could we have the 'a' added back in?

Comment: [Where's that giant S when you need it...](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105)

Comment: You think missing article is problem?

Comment: @Yannis I wouldn't call this an pluralization bug :)

Comment: @Undo Details like that shouldn't stop a good old fashioned bludgeoning.

Comment: +1 I brought a similar point up in a [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179355/duplicate-question-close-reason-says-already-has-an-answer-which-is-often-fal) about the language/pluralization used in the prior closure system. Drive me nuts.

Comment: With my basic understanding of grammar, "marked as *a* duplicate" sounds like it's among other duplicates, while "marked as duplicate" sounds like it's being marked with a ~duplicate~ stamp, like "APPROVED". I think the two are correct.

Comment: This aren't really grammatically uncorrect, but I ain't care much either way.

Comment: Me fail English? That's unpossible!

Answer (score 1):

Only if [duplicate](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/duplicate_2) can't be an adjective.

But even as an adjective, I am not sure whether this is grammatically correct since I am not a native English speaker.

If I really care, I think the following may be even better...

> ### marked as duplicate of another/some other question(s) by [Grammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammer#Other) long ago

---

Or, we shall simply treat this as grammatically correct in the world of Jeff.

Comment: Jeff is long gone, sir. He doesn't work for SE anymore.

Comment: @Asad can't you even think of him for a moment?